# When does a field of for which a set of matrices is defined on become important?

Tags: matrices, finite-fields

I have already gone through several linear algebra related courses without any notion of a field and I am having trouble reading a serious linear algebra book that talks about infinite field, so and so forth.

Obviously then, the notion of a field has little practical value in applied linear algebra. But my question is when or under what context do we MUST mention the field of which something is defined on? Can someone show me an elementary example for my small brain?

Comment: It is actually very important.  The most obvious example that comes to mind is Jordan canonical form.

Comment: Linear algebra over finite fields has important applications in cryptography, for example.

Comment: In number theory and cryptoography you also have lots of fields and you have to distinguish between them.

Comment: Can someone kindly explain why this particular book uses the phrase "suppose k is an infinite field, then..." before stating something trivial, like all system of equation $A\vec x = b$ can either have 0, 1, or infinite solutions?

Comment: Depends on what you mean by "applied linear algebra." If you mean physics, sure, but the notion of field can be quite useful in other areas, like encryption.

Comment: Because if $k$ isn't infinite, then there are only finitely many possible $x$, total, so it obviously can't be infinite.

Comment: I would say instead of infinite/finite, the characteristic of the field is more interesting.

Comment: For example the linear equation $0\cdot x=0$ has exactly $43$ solutions $x$ in the field $\Bbb{Z}_{43}$ of forty-three elements. OTOH the equation $0\cdot x+0\cdot y=0$ has $43^2$ solutions with $x,y\in \Bbb{Z}_{43}$. I think that the author of that text didn't want to modify the statement to read *... system of equations $A\vec{x}=\vec{b}$ can have either $0$ or $q^k$ solutions in the field $\Bbb{F}_q$, where $k$ is a non-negative integer less than or equal to the number of variables and $q$ is the number of elements of the field...*

Comment: The most important application of finite fields I've heard of are the error correcting codes extensively used in digital memory devices. For example the compact disk would have been unthinkable without them.